# Why the HAXM configuration memory is too low "969 MB"? It is not compatible with AVD API level 23 which require 1 GB RAM

Tags: android, memory, android-virtual-device, ram, haxm

This is the error messages shown in **Android Studio 1.4** console

```
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
emulator: device fd:560
HAXM is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode
emulator: The memory needed by this AVD exceeds the max specified in your HAXM configuration.
emulator: AVD      RAM size = 1024 MB
emulator: HAXM max RAM size = 969 MB
emulator: You might want to adjust your AVD RAM size and/or HAXM configuration to run in fast virt mode.
Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 3):

You should run HAXM installer from `<android-sdk-location>/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/` and during installation set amount of RAM available to HAXM to 1024 MB or more.

If there is not `extras/intel` directory then launch Android SDK Manager, go to `Extras`, select `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)` and press `Install`.

Comment: I have already done this.I have uninstalled Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager from the control panel and reinstall it from the Android SDK Manager ->Extras->Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator and then again installed it but the allowed RAM Range is less than 969 MB

Comment: What amount of RAM was set during installation?

Answer (score 0):

It is the first time you try to open the emulator, in my experience why i receive that warning its because i saturate the memory with others app, make sure you close other instances and clear the memory.

Other thing you can try its in the menu of *AVD Manager*, in the *advanced settings* increase the memory **RAM** of the virtual device you have configured.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: You mean you should decrease your memory RAM in AVD, it has to be lower than the maximum allowed in HAXM

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in Android Studio Arctic Fox and solved it in a curious way.

1.- I opened the previous version of Android Studio I was using (4.2.1), and ran an Android project there. Android Studio 4.2.1 Opened the emulator successfully.

2.- I came back to Arctic fox and launched my current Android project on it. The emulator ran the App correctly, as it was the same emulator I used for step 1.

3.- I closed both Android Studio 4.2.1 and the AVD. Relaunched the App on Arctic Fox, and the HAXM memory issue was gone. I can run Apps again.