# Unable to launch AVD in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to run a simple "Hello World" android project but getting the following error.

```
D:\AndroidSDK\tools\emulator.exe -avd Nexus_6_API_23 -netspeed full -netdelay none
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB
emulator: device fd:628
HAXM is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
Cannot set up guest memory 'pc.ram': Invalid argument
```

I have already set the RAM of AVD to 512 MB and max RAM of HAXM is 1.7GB

Comment: are you using windows or linux os ?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: check with your HAXM allocated memory it should not less then memory u allocated to your emulator.

Comment: you might look at this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32973966/why-the-haxm-configuration-memory-is-to-low-969-mb-it-is-not-compatible-with

Comment: I have already done it still m getting the error.. I can't understand what could be the problem

Comment: try to enable virtualization mode in bios settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used marshmallow (API 23) resulting in above errors, but now I have degraded it to KitKat (API 19) and the AVD is working fine..